# How to control seeking forward and backward from control center?

Tags: ios, swift, control-center

I really try to turn it on, but with no success;) Is there any way to do this at all?

[image]

This is how I setup remote control:

```
private func setupRemoteControl() {
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.seekForwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.seekBackwardCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play))
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pause))
}
```

What do I miss?

**Pause and play works perfectly.**

Comment: If you need this slider for changing playback position, you need to set [`changePlaybackPositionCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter/1618997-changeplaybackpositioncommand)'s handler. See [How can I make the Control Center slider editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321071/how-can-i-make-the-control-center-slider-editable)

Comment: You use Key-Value Observing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Event Handler

You need to add a handler for all the event's you want to receive:

```
commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget(handler: { (event) in
    // Handle position change
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
})
```

#### Apple Documentation

> ... To respond to a particular event, register a handler with the appropriate MPRemoteCommand object.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand